# Topcoder SRM 602 - Code not working for 1 system test case

Tags: python

I was practicing this [problem](http://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_statement&pm=12928). I created a solution but it is failing for a particular test case only. The problem requires to find the maximum number of intersecting rectangles when one rectangle is placed over other (intersecting with previously placed rectangle) such that the intersecting area is greater than `limit`(provided with input). The input contains the sides of different rectangles available to use.

My solution places the rectangles such that max of width or length is placed on one side to achieve maximum area. Also, it loops over all the rectangles to find if the new one if added to the existing pile will still make the intersecting area greater than `limit`.

Can somebody help me in finding the mistake in my solution?

```
class PilingRectsDiv2:
    def getmax(self, X, Y, limit):
        maxX = 200
        maxY = 200
        count = 0
        for i in range(0,len(X)):
            maxOfXandY = max(X[i],Y[i])
            minOfXandY = min(X[i],Y[i])
            if(min(maxX,maxOfXandY)*min(maxY,minOfXandY)>=limit):
                maxX = min(maxX,maxOfXandY)
                maxY = min(maxY,minOfXandY)
                count += 1
        if count==0:
            count = -1
        return count
```

Test case for which it is failing:

```
Args:
{{77, 134, 82, 80, 54, 104, 18, 114, 75, 24, 86, 167, 178, 150, 192, 10, 50, 192, 79, 151, 1, 16, 56, 177, 197, 127, 188, 63, 5, 142, 80, 165, 164, 137, 34}, {128, 42, 156, 153, 191, 115, 90, 166, 126, 102, 198, 9, 152, 102, 105, 3, 135, 21, 28, 39, 161, 32, 86, 44, 46, 152, 156, 58, 40, 74, 192, 194, 60, 167, 151}, 728}
```

Expected output: 30

Returned output from code: 29

Comment: What exactly does *"failing"* mean? Errors (provide full traceback)? Unexpected outputs (provide expected and actual outputs)?

Comment: Also, describe the problem itself, or the relevant parts of it, don't only link to it.

Comment: I have added more description about the problem and my approach to solution. Please comment if something is still missing. I have banged my head a lot to find out what I am missing here before posting the question here.